# Never mind in Chinese

Tags: translation, vocabulary

I ask someone a question, but then realize I already know the answer.  In English, I'd say: "Oh wait, never mind."  What's 口语 for "never mind" in this context?

Comment: What about mayo guanxi? is this slang or only used in Taiwan ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such as  :

> 不用了。

or

> 算了。

or

> 别管了。

Comment: +1 for 算了 and for being a minute quicker than the other answer

Comment: Of all the answers I received (算了, 没关系, 沒事, 别管了, 先别说), I think 不用了best captures the sense of "the situation has changed and hence there's no need to trouble yourself."  My best guess before asking was 算了, but I can see that that might feel a bit unnecessarily brusque.

Comment: @CullenSchaffer 先别说 sounds strange to me...

Answer (score 5):

Should be

> 没事了

So, "oh wait, never mind" will be

> 哦，等等，没事了。

Answer (score 4):

You can use 没关系 or 沒事.

To say "never mind" in general, you have a couple of choices. 算了 or 沒關係 both convey the general idea. 算了 however maybe be perceived as implying some level of impatience. In this specific context, 沒事 also works well.

But its mostly fine to use either, or both together as "算了，沒關係" (or "算了，沒事").

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario , you can say

> "先别说,我想我已经知道了."

There is a benefits to this syntax. It makes someone feel that you have a good relationship.

You can also say

> "啊,我领悟了."

It is very stylish!

Answer (score 2):

"mind" = "心意"

so my best translation

for "never mind"

is "不要 放在 心 上" , (bu-yao fang-zai xin shang)

i.e. "don't put (or carry) anything in your heart (mind)"

also,

"別 掛心", (bie gua-xin)

"不 介意" (bu jie-yi)

Please note that, 
I always suggest using '心' or '意' in this case,
because it catches the meaning of 'mind'.

Answer (score 2):

哦，我已经懂了。oh, i already know it!  or 没事儿了。 i already figure out it.

Answer (score 2):

没关系，不用了。（It's ok now, not need it）is one of the common expressions for never mind.

Some people would also double 没事 (not have business or affair), such as 没事! 没事!

Answer (score 1):

**不存在** is very popular.
**没关系** is the most use.
**不要紧** is colloquial way.

Comment: 不存在 sounds strange in that situation to me, how can it be popular ...

Comment: sorry, i only list some Chinese expressions for "never mind", for your situation, the best is "不用了" "没事了"

Comment: @EffectiveMatrix 不存在 just doesn't make sense as a translation of 'never mind' in any situation, at least in Mandarin. Maybe it's from another dialect/topolect? You need to specify it in that case. Mandarin is assumed as the default if it's not mentioned/requested in the question.